# Font-Awesome fonts not loading

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm trying to use `font awesome v4.5.0` in my project. I'm compiling my `CSS` using `LESS` and I've got the following:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@import "minimal-devices/minimal-devices.less";
@import "angular-tour/angular-tour.less";
@import "font-awesome/font-awesome.less";
@import "my-fonts.less";
@import "my-base.less";
@import "my-media.less";
@import "sce-style.less";
```

I'm using `GulpJS` to create one large `css` file and this is in my `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src([DIRSOURCE + 'assets/less/sce.less'])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename("style.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIRDEST + 'assets/css'));
});
```

When I load up my page I get this shown in the console:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8000/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0
(index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as In my project I have the directory font-awesome with the font-awesome.less file.

Anyone have any guidance on this?

Comment: Do you have font files in your project? Maybe you have wrong version of them.

Comment: I do, they are contained in `assets/fonts` my `LESS` variable for the path is `../../fonts`

Answer (score 2):

Issue was linked to the path I had set to the font directory. I updated within `variables.less`  on line 4 to `@fa-font-path "../fonts";` or alternatively to avoid any of this hassle I could have uncommented line 7 and used the `CDN` below:

```
//@fa-font-path:        "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/fonts"; // for referencing Bootstrap CDN font files directly
```